# Can I combine 2 nonclustered indexes (a column appears in key list of idx_1 and appears in include list of idx2)

Tags: sql-server

I have a nonclustered index (idx_1) with first_name, last_name in key list and marks include list. Another non clustered index (idx_2) with first_name, last_name and marks in key list and no columns in include list. I wish to combine these two indexes into a single index. What would be the optimal solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! You should drop idx_1. But, before that, it is not a bad idea to analyze index usage. Check out how many seeks, scans are on every index. You can use this T-SQL query.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(IX.OBJECT_ID) Table_Name
       ,IX.name AS Index_Name
       ,IX.type_desc Index_Type
       ,SUM(PS.[used_page_count]) * 8 IndexSizeKB
       ,IXUS.user_seeks AS NumOfSeeks
       ,IXUS.user_scans AS NumOfScans
       ,IXUS.user_lookups AS NumOfLookups
       ,IXUS.user_updates AS NumOfUpdates
       ,IXUS.last_user_seek AS LastSeek
       ,IXUS.last_user_scan AS LastScan
       ,IXUS.last_user_lookup AS LastLookup
       ,IXUS.last_user_update AS LastUpdate
FROM sys.indexes IX
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats IXUS ON IXUS.index_id = IX.index_id AND IXUS.OBJECT_ID = IX.OBJECT_ID
INNER JOIN sys.dm_db_partition_stats PS on PS.object_id=IX.object_id
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(IX.OBJECT_ID,'IsUserTable') = 1
GROUP BY OBJECT_NAME(IX.OBJECT_ID) ,IX.name ,IX.type_desc ,IXUS.user_seeks ,IXUS.user_scans ,IXUS.user_lookups,IXUS.user_updates ,IXUS.last_user_seek ,IXUS.last_user_scan ,IXUS.last_user_lookup ,IXUS.last_user_update
```

Besides that, take a look at following link [sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-index-usage-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)